# Continuous Date Ranges - Gaps and Islands

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, gaps-and-islands

```
CREATE TABLE T1
    (Asset_Id int, Trailer_Id int, AssignStart datetime, AssignEnd DATETIME)
;
INSERT INTO T1
    (Asset_Id, Trailer_Id, AssignStart, AssignEnd)
VALUES
    (37124, 32607, '2018-04-19 08:55:00', '2018-05-05 10:00:00.000'),
    (37124, 32607, '2018-05-05 11:23:00', NULL),
    (33000, 30000, '2018-04-01 15:00:00', '2018-04-15 10:30:00.000'),
    (34000, 31000, '2018-04-05 10:00:00', '2018-04-10 09:30:00.000'),
    (34000, 32500, '2018-04-10 09:31:00', NULL),
    (37000, 32600, '2018-04-19 08:55:00', '2018-04-25 08:30:00.000'),
    (37000, 32600, '2018-04-25 09:23:00', '2018-04-25 10:00:00.000'),
    (37000, 32600, '2018-04-25 11:23:00', '2018-04-30 15:00:00.000'),
    (37000, 32600, '2018-04-30 16:15:00', '2018-04-30 17:30:00.000'),
    (37000, 32600, '2018-05-01 18:23:00', NULL),
    (38000, 36000, '2018-05-01 10:00:00', '2018-05-10 06:30:00.000'),
    (38000, 36000, '2018-05-15 09:00:00', '2018-05-20 11:00:00.000'),
    (38000, 36000, '2018-05-20 12:00:00', NULL),
    (33000, 30000, '2018-05-01 10:00:00', NULL)
;
```

I have the following sample data -

```
Asset_Id    Trailer_Id  AssignStart             AssignEnd
37124       32607       2018-04-19 08:55:00.000 2018-05-05 10:00:00.000
37124       32607       2018-05-05 11:23:00.000 NULL
33000       30000       2018-04-01 15:00:00.000 2018-04-15 10:30:00.000
34000       31000       2018-04-05 10:00:00.000 2018-04-10 09:30:00.000
34000       32500       2018-04-10 09:31:00.000 NULL
37000       32600       2018-04-19 08:55:00.000 2018-04-25 08:30:00.000
37000       32600       2018-04-25 09:23:00.000 2018-04-25 10:00:00.000
37000       32600       2018-04-25 11:23:00.000 2018-04-30 15:00:00.000
37000       32600       2018-04-30 16:15:00     2018-04-30 17:30:00.000
37000       32600       2018-05-01 18:23:00     NULL
38000       36000       2018-05-01 10:00:00.000 2018-05-10 06:30:00.000
38000       36000       2018-05-15 09:00:00.000 2018-05-20 11:00:00.000
38000       36000       2018-05-20 12:00:00.000 NULL
33000       30000       2018-05-01 10:00:00.000 NULL
```

As you can see some of the assignments between Assets and Trailers are ended and started again on the same day - except for last row - Gaps and Islands

Example (1)

```
Asset_Id    Trailer_Id  AssignStart             AssignEnd
37000       32600       2018-04-19 08:55:00.000 2018-04-25 08:30:00.000
37000       32600       2018-04-25 09:23:00.000 2018-04-25 10:00:00.000
37000       32600       2018-04-25 11:23:00.000 2018-04-30 15:00:00.000
37000       32600       2018-04-30 16:15:00.000 2018-04-30 17:30:00.000
37000       32600       2018-05-01 18:23:00.000 NULL
```

Output for this sample I am expecting is

```
Asset_Id    Trailer_Id  AssignStart             AssignEnd
37000       32600       2018-04-19 08:55:00.000 2018-04-30 17:30:00.000
37000       32600       2018-05-01 18:23:00.000 NULL
```

Now this is another section with the Gaps and Islands.
Some of assignments between the same assets and trailers are ended and then started again on a future date

Example (2)

```
Asset_Id    Trailer_Id  AssignStart             AssignEnd
33000       30000       2018-04-01 15:00:00.000 2018-04-15 10:30:00.000
33000       30000       2018-05-01 10:00:00.000 NULL
```

Output for this sample I am expecting is

```
Asset_Id    Trailer_Id  AssignStart             AssignEnd
33000       30000       2018-04-01 15:00:00.000 2018-04-15 10:30:00.000
33000       30000       2018-05-01 10:00:00.000 NULL
```

Example (3)

```
Asset_Id    Trailer_Id  AssignStart             AssignEnd
38000       36000       2018-05-01 10:00:00.000 2018-05-10 06:30:00.000
38000       36000       2018-05-15 09:00:00.000 2018-05-20 11:00:00.000
38000       36000       2018-05-20 12:00:00.000 NULL
```

Output for this sample I am expecting is

```
Asset_Id    Trailer_Id  AssignStart             AssignEnd
38000       36000       2018-05-01 10:00:00.000 2018-05-10 06:30:00.000
38000       36000       2018-05-15 09:00:00.000 NULL
```

I struggling to write a query that will provide the following output

```
Asset_Id    Trailer_Id  AssignStart             AssignEnd
37124       32607       2018-04-19 08:55:00.000 NULL
33000       30000       2018-04-01 15:00:00.000 2018-04-15 10:30:00.000
34000       31000       2018-04-05 10:00:00.000 2018-04-10 09:30:00.000
34000       32500       2018-04-10 09:31:00.000 NULL
37000       32600       2018-04-19 08:55:00.000 2018-04-30 17:30:00.000
37000       32600       2018-05-01 18:23:00.000 NULL
38000       36000       2018-05-01 10:00:00.000 2018-05-10 06:30:00.000
38000       36000       2018-05-15 09:00:00.000 NULL
33000       30000       2018-05-01 10:00:00.000 NULL
```

Using the answer from this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16596168/3266499) as a base [this is my attempt](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/98128/2), it's not quite right

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the recursive approach , with the help of a CTE.
For this , I added a `Row_Number` so , to be sure that it's the next record verified.

Then creating the recursive CTE...named `cte`. Here it's important the field `rn as rn_init` - this is the base when it's creating the chain of records.

```
;
WITH fr AS -- first records
(
SELECT [Asset_Id], [Trailer_Id], [AssignStart], [AssignEnd]
  ,ROW_NUMBER()OVER( PARTITION BY [Asset_Id], [Trailer_Id] ORDER BY 
   [AssignStart], [AssignEnd]) AS rn
FROM  T1
)
,cte AS
(
 SELECT [Asset_Id], [Trailer_Id]
      , [AssignStart] as [AssignStart_init] , [AssignEnd] as [AssignEnd_Init] 
      , [AssignStart] as [AssignStart],  [AssignEnd] as [AssignEnd]
      , 0 as lvl
      , rn as rn
      , rn as rn_init
 FROM fr
 --WHERE [AssignEnd] is not null

 UNION ALL

 SELECT 
     T1.[Asset_Id], T1.[Trailer_Id]
     ,C.[AssignStart_init],C.[AssignEnd_Init]
     ,T1.[AssignStart], T1.[AssignEnd]
     ,C.lvl + 1 
     ,T1.rn
     ,C.rn_init
 FROM fr AS T1
     INNER JOIN cte as C
        ON T1.[Asset_Id] = C.[Asset_Id]
        AND T1.[Trailer_Id] = C.[Trailer_Id]
        AND CONVERT(DATE,C.[AssignEnd]) = CONVERT(DATE,T1.[AssignStart])
        AND C.[AssignEnd] <= T1.[AssignStart]
        AND C.rn + 1 = T1.rn
)
```

Here is dealing with `NULL` case for the AssignEnd 
and also important , to count the 'chain of records' `count(rn_init) as c_rn_init`. Base on this, it's later filtered.

```
--select * from cte
,myPrecious AS
(
select  --C.* 
   C.[Asset_Id],c.[Trailer_Id]
    ,MIN([AssignStart]) as AssignStart
    --,MAX([AssignEnd]) as AssignEnd
    ,CASE WHEN MAX(isnull([AssignEnd],[AssignStart])) = MAX([AssignStart]) THEN NULL ELSE MAX(isnull([AssignEnd],[AssignStart])) END as [AssignEnd]
    ,count(rn_init) as c_rn_init
 from cte as c
group by C.[Asset_Id],c.[Trailer_Id], C.rn_init

 )
```

This if the final query.Added Row_number , so to filter out records , `ORDER BY c_rn_init DESC`

```
 SELECT 
  Asset_Id,Trailer_Id,AssignStart,AssignEnd
  --,c_rn_init
  --,rn
  FROM(
          SELECT * 
               ,row_number() OVER(PARTITION BY [Asset_Id],[Trailer_Id] , AssignEnd ORDER BY c_rn_init DESC) as rn
          FROM myPrecious
      )A
 WHERE A.rn = 1
 order by [Asset_Id],[Trailer_Id]  ,[AssignStart],[AssignEnd]
```

The output:

```
Asset_Id    Trailer_Id  AssignStart         AssignEnd
33000       30000       01/04/2018 15:00:00 15/04/2018 10:30:00
33000       30000       01/05/2018 10:00:00 null
34000       31000       05/04/2018 10:00:00 10/04/2018 09:30:00
34000       32500       10/04/2018 09:31:00 null
37000       32600       19/04/2018 08:55:00 30/04/2018 17:30:00
37000       32600       01/05/2018 18:23:00 null
37124       32607       19/04/2018 08:55:00 null
38000       36000       01/05/2018 10:00:00 10/05/2018 06:30:00
38000       36000       15/05/2018 09:00:00 null
```

[dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=532fa0533e147f19e3cacbcc2dc6ab77)

Answer (score 1):

My idea is to get the AssignStart value, from the next record and do a difference in day between [AssignEnd] (of the current row) and AssignStart (of the next row) (Step1)

if it's sql server 2012 ,we can use LEAD

```
LEAD([AssignStart],1,[AssignStart]) OVER(PARTITION BY [Asset_Id], [Trailer_Id] ORDER BY [AssignStart]) as next_AssignStart
```

if it's 2008, we can not use LEAD , so use OUTER APPLY to get the record:

```
 OUTER APPLY
   (SELECT TOP(1) T2.[AssignStart]
      FROM T1 as T2
      WHERE T1.[Asset_Id] = T2.[Asset_Id]
          AND T1.[Trailer_Id] = T2.[Trailer_Id] 
          AND T1.[AssignStart]<T2.[AssignStart] 
      ORDER BY T2.[AssignStart] ASC 
   )OA
```

this will give me the `AssignStart` of the next row , base on `[Asset_Id], [Trailer_Id]`

Step2 : do that difference column : `DATEDIFF(DAY,[AssignEnd],next_AssignStart)`

```
SELECT 
  [Asset_Id], [Trailer_Id], [AssignStart], [AssignEnd]
  ,next_AssignStart
  ,IsNUll(DATEDIFF(DAY,[AssignEnd],next_AssignStart),0) as diff_days
FROM
(
SELECT
    [Asset_Id], [Trailer_Id],T1.[AssignStart], [AssignEnd]
    --,LEAD([AssignStart],1,[AssignStart]) OVER(PARTITION BY [Asset_Id], [Trailer_Id] ORDER BY [AssignStart]) as next_AssignStart
    ,OA.[AssignStart] as next_AssignStart
FROM
   T1
   OUTER APPLY
   (SELECT TOP(1) T2.[AssignStart]
      FROM T1 as T2
      WHERE T1.[Asset_Id] = T2.[Asset_Id]
          AND T1.[Trailer_Id] = T2.[Trailer_Id] 
          AND T1.[AssignStart]<T2.[AssignStart] 
      ORDER BY T2.[AssignStart] ASC 
   )OA
)A
ORDER BY [Asset_Id], [Trailer_Id], [AssignStart], [AssignEnd]
```

Step3: do a group by on this column, from step2

```
SELECT 
  [Asset_Id], [Trailer_Id]
  ,MIN([AssignStart]) as [AssignStart]
  ,CASE WHEN MAX(isnull([AssignEnd],[AssignStart])) = MAX([AssignStart]) THEN NULL ELSE MAX(isnull([AssignEnd],[AssignStart])) END as [AssignEnd]
FROM
(
SELECT
    [Asset_Id], [Trailer_Id], T1.[AssignStart], [AssignEnd]
    --,LEAD([AssignStart],1,[AssignStart]) OVER(PARTITION BY [Asset_Id], [Trailer_Id] ORDER BY [AssignStart]) as next_AssignStart
    ,OA.[AssignStart] as next_AssignStart
FROM
   T1
   OUTER APPLY
   (SELECT TOP(1) T2.[AssignStart]
      FROM T1 as T2
      WHERE T1.[Asset_Id] = T2.[Asset_Id]
          AND T1.[Trailer_Id] = T2.[Trailer_Id] 
          AND T1.[AssignStart]<T2.[AssignStart] 
      ORDER BY T2.[AssignStart] ASC 
   )OA
)A
GROUP BY [Asset_Id], [Trailer_Id], IsNUll(DATEDIFF(DAY,[AssignEnd],next_AssignStart),0)
ORDER BY [Asset_Id], [Trailer_Id],[AssignStart]
```

output:

```
Asset_Id    Trailer_Id  AssignStart         AssignEnd
33000       30000       01/04/2018 15:00:00 15/04/2018 10:30:00
33000       30000       01/05/2018 10:00:00 null
34000       31000       05/04/2018 10:00:00 10/04/2018 09:30:00
34000       32500       10/04/2018 09:31:00 null
37000       32600       19/04/2018 08:55:00 null
37124       32607       19/04/2018 08:55:00 null
38000       36000       01/05/2018 10:00:00 10/05/2018 06:30:00
38000       36000       15/05/2018 09:00:00 null
```

ps: added Order by, so I can verify much easier.

ps2: because ,`NULL` it's ignored in MAX, I used this expression to handle the upper part of the interval

[dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=730cceb388c1b2d0767b7d944866d39d)

Comment: Hit a bug.  If I change this row in the sample data `37000       32600       2018-04-30 18:23:00.000 NULL` to the following day `37000       32600       2018-05-01 18:23:00.000 NULL` - the results are not as expected

Comment: And in this case what will be the output ?

Comment: Expected results for the change is: 

`37000       32600      2018-04-19 08:55:00        2018-04-30 17:30:00.000
37000       32600       2018-05-01 18:23:00.000 NULL`

Answer (score 1):

I present my solution for T-SQL.

[Fiddle SQL Server 2017](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=cecb1cde2e7cb9f3f52db562139ad613)

**The problem:**

We need to pack records by overlapping date range (base time unit 'day') partitioned by Asset and Trailer.

**The solution:**

Packing overlapping date ranges requires 3 steps:

*Step 1*: determine a GroupStart

```
    select Asset_Id, Trailer_Id, AssignStart, AssignEnd
                    , case when max(AssignEnd) 
                        over (partition by Asset_Id, Trailer_Id order by AssignEnd, AssignStart rows between unbounded preceding and 1 preceding)
                            >= AssignStart
                        then 0 else 1 end GroupStart
                from  (
                    select Asset_Id, Trailer_Id, 
                           convert(date, AssignStart) AssignStart, 
                           convert(date, coalesce(AssignEnd, '99991231')) AssignEnd
                    from T1
            ) t0
```

*Step 2*: determine the Groups

```
select Asset_Id, Trailer_Id, AssignStart, AssignEnd, sum(GroupStart) over (partition by Asset_Id, Trailer_Id order by AssignStart) Grp 
        from (...) t0
) p0
```

*Step 3*: determine the packed date range

```
select Asset_Id, Trailer_Id, min(AssignStart) AssignStart, max(AssignEnd) AssignEnd 
    from (...) p1
    group by Asset_Id, Trailer_Id, Grp
```

Setup:

```
CREATE TABLE T1
    (Asset_Id int, Trailer_Id int, AssignStart datetime, AssignEnd DATETIME)
;
INSERT INTO T1
    (Asset_Id, Trailer_Id, AssignStart, AssignEnd)
VALUES
    (37124, 32607, '2018-04-19 08:55:00', '2018-05-05 10:00:00.000'),
    (37124, 32607, '2018-05-05 11:23:00', NULL),
    (33000, 30000, '2018-04-01 15:00:00', '2018-04-15 10:30:00.000'),
    (34000, 31000, '2018-04-05 10:00:00', '2018-04-10 09:30:00.000'),
    (34000, 32500, '2018-04-10 09:31:00', NULL),
    (37000, 32600, '2018-04-19 08:55:00', '2018-04-25 08:30:00.000'),
    (37000, 32600, '2018-04-25 09:23:00', '2018-04-25 10:00:00.000'),
    (37000, 32600, '2018-04-25 11:23:00', '2018-04-30 15:00:00.000'),
    (37000, 32600, '2018-04-30 16:15:00', '2018-04-30 17:30:00.000'),
    (37000, 32600, '2018-05-01 18:23:00', NULL),
    (38000, 36000, '2018-05-01 10:00:00', '2018-05-10 06:30:00.000'),
    (38000, 36000, '2018-05-15 09:00:00', '2018-05-20 11:00:00.000'),
    (38000, 36000, '2018-05-20 12:00:00', NULL),
    (33000, 30000, '2018-05-01 10:00:00', NULL)
```

Full Query:

```
 with packed as (
    select Asset_Id, Trailer_Id, min(AssignStart) AssignStart, max(AssignEnd) AssignEnd from (
        select Asset_Id, Trailer_Id, AssignStart, AssignEnd, sum(GroupStart) over (partition by Asset_Id, Trailer_Id order by AssignStart) Grp from (
            select Asset_Id, Trailer_Id, AssignStart, AssignEnd
                , case when max(AssignEnd) 
                    over (partition by Asset_Id, Trailer_Id order by AssignEnd, AssignStart rows between unbounded preceding and 1 preceding)
                        >= AssignStart
                    then 0 else 1 end GroupStart
            from (
                    select Asset_Id, Trailer_Id, 
                           convert(date, AssignStart) AssignStart, 
                           convert(date, coalesce(AssignEnd, '99991231')) AssignEnd
                    from T1
            ) t0
        ) p0
    ) p1
    group by Asset_Id, Trailer_Id, Grp
)
select Asset_Id, Trailer_Id, AssignStart, nullif(AssignEnd, '99991231')
from packed
order by Asset_Id, Trailer_Id, AssignStart;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try the self-join as an alternative.

In my environment (with the sample data) it is generating less reads than the OUTER APPLY. and producing a less costly execution plan. But when I add different Indexes the OUTER APPLY sometimes comes out on top.

```
--SET STATISTICS IO ON
--SET STATISTICS TIME ON

;WITH cteSequence AS
(
SELECT 
    CUR.Asset_Id 
    ,CUR.Trailer_Id
    ,CUR.AssignStart
    ,CUR.AssignEnd
    ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Asset_Id,Trailer_Id ORDER BY AssignStart) AS SEQ
FROM 
    T1 CUR
)
SELECT 
    CUR.Asset_Id 
    ,CUR.Trailer_Id
    ,MIN(CUR.AssignStart) AS AssignStart
    ,CASE 
        WHEN MAX(COALESCE(NXT.[AssignEnd],CUR.[AssignStart])) = MAX(NXT.[AssignStart]) THEN NULL 
        ELSE MAX(COALESCE(CUR.[AssignEnd],NXT.[AssignStart])) END as [AssignEnd]
FROM 
    cteSequence CUR
        LEFT JOIN cteSequence NXT
            ON
            CUR.Asset_Id = NXT.Asset_Id
            AND
            CUR.Trailer_Id = NXT.Trailer_Id
            AND
            CUR.SEQ = NXT.SEQ-1
GROUP BY 
    CUR.Asset_Id 
    ,CUR.Trailer_Id
    ,COALESCE(DATEDIFF(DD,CUR.AssignEnd,NXT.AssignStart),0)
```

Comment: Thanks for this however, this suffers from the same bug as sabin's answer.
If I change this row in the sample data `37000 32600 2018-04-30 18:23:00.000 NULL` to the following day `37000 32600 2018-05-01 18:23:00.000 NULL` - the results are not as expected.

Expected results for the change is: `37000 32600 2018-04-19 08:55:00 2018-04-30 17:30:00.000` `37000 32600 2018-05-01 18:23:00.000 NULL`